# Array is not stored correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-redux

i have the code:

```
for (let key in data ){
    let info = data[ key ];
    arr.push(<li>{info.name}</li>);
}
this.setState({
    response: arr,
    arr: []
  })
```

but when i try:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
    response: prevState.response.push(<li>{data.name}</li>)
}))
```

I get just a number instead of an array of data.

How can I fix this?

Comment: what's the return of `push()`?

Comment: Its not a good practice to push `jsx` into `state`. One should set only the data and then use it to render

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`push` returns the length of the array after insertion, use `concat` instead

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
    response: prevState.response.concat([<li>{data.name}</li>])
}))
```